# Select Count Distinct values from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Users Table:

```
+-----------+----------+------------+-------------+
| name      | fb_id    | date       | flipbook    |
+-----------+----------+------------+-------------+
| Tia       | 66783722 | 1975-09-18 |  june 2014  |
| Nikki     | 10438259 | 1972-03-04 |  july 2014  |
| Yamila    | 73370629 | 1972-03-04 | august 2014 | 
+-----------+----------+------------+-------------+
```

Visits Table:

```
+-----------+----------+------------+-------------+
| Name      | fb_id    | Date       |  Flipbook   |
+-----------+----------+------------+-------------+
| Tia       | 66783722 | 1975-09-18 | june 2014   |
| Nikki     | 10438259 | 1972-03-04 | august 2014 |
| Nikki     | 10438259 | 1972-04-04 | october 2014|
+-----------+----------+------------+-------------+
```

I want the query to return all users from from user Table and count the number of flipbooks, for example:

```
[1]
name => Tia, 
fb_id = 66783722,
date => 1975-09-18,
count_flip => 1 (june 2014 is in both tables so we count it as 1)

[2]
name => Nikki, 
fb_id = 10438259,
date => 1972-03-04,
count_flip => 3 (because in the first table we have june 2014 and in the second table we have august 2014 and october 2014, so no duplicates)

[3]
name => Yamila, 
fb_id = 73370629,
date => 1972-03-04,
count_flip => 1 (because we have august 2014 in the first table and she is not mentioned in the second one)
```

I tryed to do this query:

```
SELECT u.*, (SELECT COUNT(Distinct flipbook) FROM visits v WHERE v.fb_id = u.fb_id) as count_flip FROM users u
```

But the problem is I am missing the users that are in the users table but not in the visits table. So for the example above I wouldn't see "Yamila" in my query.

Any thoughts how to fix this?

Comment: Could you create a http://sqlfiddle.com/?

Comment: Do a LEFT JOIN with GROUP BY!

Comment: A bad data structure but an interesting question.

Comment: Well is because we did changes to the application while already running.

Comment: you really shouldn't have two tables storing the same data (unless one is an archive).  you should merge the tables into one and add a flag as to whether the data is users or visits.

Comment: Actually this is not the actual tables, is just for example, the real ones have totally different columns, and only have the fb_id  and flipbook columns in common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of thinking about the logic is that you want to count 1 for the users table and then add up all non-matching flipbook values for the `name` in the `visits` table.  This suggests a correlated subquery:

```
select u.*,
       (select 1 + count(*)
        from visits v
        where v.name = u.name and v.flipbook <> u.flipbook
       ) as nr
from users u;
```

EDIT:

Another way to do what you want is less efficient (assuming you have the right indexes for the above query):

```
select u.*, uv.nr
from users u join
     (select u.name, count(distinct flipbook) as nr
      from ((select name, flipbook from users) union all
            (select name, flipbook from visits)
           ) uv
      group by u.name
     ) uv
     on u.name = uv.name;
```

Comment: I will check now your query

Comment: I tryed it, but it's failing somewhere, because only like 60% of the results are accurate.

Comment: @Edward . . . Can you set up a SQL Fiddle with examples that do not work?  This query should work on the data you have put into your question.

Comment: Think you are missing the INNER JOIN in the 2nd example.

Comment: Alright seems is working in the SQL Fiddle, I had a mistake in my application, so it works now.

Comment: I only changed select 1 + count(DISTINCT flipbook), because I don't want to get duplicate flipbooks from visits.

Comment: @Edward . . . Your sample data had no duplicates in `flipbook`, so the `distinct` didn't seem necessary.  It incurs extra overhead when used.

Comment: True, was my bad, I will take all the blame.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just do this:-

```
SELECT users.name, users.fb_id, users.date, COUNT(DISTINCT visits.Flipbook) + 1 AS count_flip
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN visits
ON users.fb_id = visits.fb_id
AND users.flipbook != visits.flipbook
GROUP BY users.name, users.fb_id, users.date
```

Does a LEFT OUTER JOIN to get a row for each matching user with a different date. Then just ad one to the resulting count (to count the original field on the users table).

This avoids any sub queries.